# SQL - select highest win / loss

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table 'games' and want to select the highest win and loss of the team I want.

I have table like this:

```
ID team1 team2 score1 score2
1  KVA   PLZ   8      5
2  MLB   KVA   0      8
3  PLZ   SPA   0      6
4  SPA   MLB   5      2
5  KVA   SPA   3      5
6  PLZ   MLB   7      1
```

Two examples:

1) I want to select the highest win of team 'KVA', then I want to get this row:

```
ID team1 team2 score1 score2
2  MLB   KVA   0      8
```

2) I want to select the highest loss of team 'PLZ', then I want to get:

```
ID team1 team2 score1 score2
3  PLZ   SPA   0      6
```

Requirements:

- Winning 10:0 is better than 11:1
- Losing 1:11 is better than 0:10

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thank you for posting your requirements. Now please post your attempt...

Comment: which one is better in term of winning, `10:0` or `25:5`?

Comment: 25:5 is better than 10:0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic approach is to sort by difference in scores and then a second column for tie-breakers. It's slightly complicated because the team can be in either of the team columns.

Highest Win of KVA:

```
Select
    *
From
    games
Where
    team1 = 'KVA' Or
    team2 = 'KVA'
Order By
    Case When team1 = 'KVA' Then score1 - score2 else score2 - score1 end Desc,
    Case When team1 = 'KVA' then score1 else score2 end
Limit 1
```

Highest Loss of PLZ

```
Select
    *
From
    games
Where
    team1 = 'PLZ' Or
    team2 = 'PLZ'
Order By
    Case team1 when 'PLZ' Then score2 - score1 else score1 - score2 end Desc,
    Case team1 when 'PLZ' then score2 else score1 end
Limit 1
```

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/766e6/6)